# Send WYSIWYG editor Value Using Ajax in CakePHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp

i am using summernot WYSIWYG editor for textarea.  one input field of a form used to in summernot WYSIWYG editor but when i submit it and send all data to cakephp controller using serialize methode but on first click it giving me empty data but when i put it on second time then my data received. my question is is there any method to send that all data of form send to controller (HTMl Rich text) Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried summernote though, but I found it a lil bit complicated with Bootstrap WYSIWYG. So I put the data of the editor in a hidden textarea before posting the ajax request. Something like this:

```
<div id="editor"></div> <!-- Rich text box -->
<textarea style="display: none;" id="msg"></textarea>

$('form').on('submit', function(e){

e.preventDefault();

$('#msg').val($('#editor').html());

$.ajax({

 //Put other parameters
data: {message: $('textarea#msg').val()},
})

})
```